# Ant Design Vue - Custom Header in Collapse Component

Tags: vue.js, antd, ant-design-vue

Hello I'am using Vue and Ant Design. So i pick Collapse Component from Ant Design: https://antdv.com/components/collapse/
My problem is that in Collapse.Panel there is a prop `header` which is `string`, but i need to put string in there (example: v0.6.1.11) and date, so i can add `margin-left: auto` or something like that in date.
Exmaple:

[image]

I tried using `white-space: pre` and then simply add spaces to achive that space between but it's not responsive solution.

How can i pass into header prop pure html so i could put something like two `<p>` tags there and then create space between title and date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [docs](https://antdv.com/components/collapse/#API), we can make use of Panel property `extra` slot.

Run this sample code

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
       text: `A dog is a type of domesticated animal.Known for its loyalty and faithfulness,it can be found as a welcome guest in many households across the world.`,
      activeKey: ['1'],
      expandIconPosition: 'left',
    };
  },
 computed:{
   currDate(){
     return new Date().toLocaleDateString()
   }
 }
});
```

```css
.ant-collapse>.ant-collapse-item>.ant-collapse-header{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ant-design-vue@1.4.11/dist/antd.min.css">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bms.test/vendor/laravel-admin/moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ant-design-vue@1.5.0/dist/antd.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  
    <a-collapse v-model="activeKey">
      <a-collapse-panel key="1" header="This is panel header 1">
        <p>{{ text }}</p>
        <div slot="extra">{{currDate}}</div>
      </a-collapse-panel>
      <a-collapse-panel key="2" header="This is panel header 2" :disabled="false">
        <p>{{ text }}</p>
        <div  slot="extra">{{currDate}}</div>
      </a-collapse-panel>
      <a-collapse-panel key="3" header="This is panel header 3" disabled>
        <p>{{ text }}</p>
        <div  slot="extra">{{currDate}}</div>
      </a-collapse-panel>
    </a-collapse>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you ! This is exactly what i needed :)

Comment: glad i could help you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code for the pupose.

```
 <a-collapse-panel key="1" header="heading 1">
        <p>Content</p>
        <template #extra><p>heading 2</p></template> <!-- for newer version -->
        <p slot="extra">heading 2</p> <!-- for older version -->
  </a-collapse-panel>
```